# How to use Dask with custom classes

Tags: dask

I am building a distributed spatial index in Python with a wrapped C++ extension. I am trying to use Dask (for the first time) instead of MPI.
The current implementation works, but has several problems.

1. The critical part is the large overhead compared to serial execution. I would expect an almost linear speed-up from the algorithm.
2. Persist does not seem to do what I expect, as timings of the first query are much longer than in the second.
3. for my eyes the code looks unidiomatic, but as said, I am new to Dask. Is there a better way of doing this?
4. I need to to do some indexing into the delayed objects when using 2d chunks. That does not occur with 1d chunks and feels weird.

The algorithm builds sorts list of particles and then builds an octree, where nodes reference contiguous blocks of particles by in the sorted array by a pair of (start, end) indices. Queries take a boundary box and search overlapping nodes in the octree collect particles actually in the boundary box from the resulting candidates. Both building and queries are purely serial.

Parallelisation is done by randomly splitting up the particles, building tree on each subset. Queries are broadcast across all sub-indices and results are concatenated back together. Dask felt like a natural fit here. I use persist to generate the index once and keep it around as I expect many queries per index.

I tried `map_blocks` but this only seems to work for array to array transformations. Further, various permutations of persist/compute have been tried.

```
from dask.delayed import delayed
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster, Client
import dask.array as da

# My custom octree index
from pyoctree import Index

# For reference, this runs on a 10 Core x 8 Thread cluster (POWER8)
cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client()

# Point count
N = 100_000_000
# Dimensionality
D = 3
# Chunk Count
K = 10
# Octree Levels
L = 5

# Delayed adapters for Dask
@delayed
def index(xs):
    """Create index"""
    return Index(L, xs)

@delayed
def query(index, ll, ur):
    """Bounding box query between lower left and upper right"""
    return index.query(*ll, *ur)

# Random input: N random points in 3d
array   = da.random.random((N, 3), chunks=(N//K,3)).astype(np.float32)
# Split array
splits  = array.to_delayed() 
# Create index
indices = [index(split[0]).persist() for split in splits]
# This takes roughly 100ms

# Execute a query
queries = [query(index, (0.25, 0.25, 0.25), (0.35, 0.35, 0.35)) for index in indices]
# Merge results
parts   = [da.from_delayed(query, shape=(np.nan,3), dtype=np.float32) for query in queries]
parts   = [part.compute_chunk_sizes() for part in parts]
final   = da.concatenate(parts)
result  = final.compute()
# This takes 100s the first time and 800ms afterwards
```

Serial execution with the same parameters takes 240s to build the index and 6ms for a single query. With Dask it is 100s building and 800ms per query. Increasing the particle number N by 10x, I get 11s per query and 240s to build the index. So it would seem Dask adds severe penality that scales in N.

I am grateful for any hints.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without profiling, but my guess is that you're including your spatial index in every task, and so are being hurt by excessive serialization.

I recommend reading through this document to learn how to identify costs: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/phases-of-computation.html

And this document to learn about avoiding the serialization of large objects: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed-best-practices.html#avoid-repeatedly-putting-large-inputs-into-delayed-calls

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem regarding performance. For the future, how would I diagnose this using the Dask profiler?

Comment: As noted in the first link above you wouldn't.  That document has suggestions on how to identify and profile serialization costs.